# class implementation with inheritance and constructor issue on scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor

For theory of computation, i'd like to make a class as follows

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class Alphabet extends mutable.Set[String] {

  def *(that: Alphabet): Alphabet = {
    var prod = new Alphabet
    for (x <- this; y <- that)
      prod += (x + y)
    prod
  }

  def pow(n: Int): Alphabet = {
    var prod = new Alphabet
    for (i <- 1 to n) 
      prod *= this
    prod
  }

}
```

but Scala IDE tells me on the line 3 (class Alphabet...) "class Alphabet needs to be abstract, since: it has 4 unimplemented members" what should i do? I'm a beginner on this language

Comment: right-click on the error, it'll tell you what to do ...
Generally, extends Sets (and using mutable sets) is almost always not what you want to do in scala, BTW. It sounds like you are jumping into coding a bit too soon. Perhaps, it makes sense to read a beginner's book first?

Comment: There's no option available to correct my error.  I've been reading books, but i never found an example where a class extends a set (
since it's not a good idea in Scala, so you say...). Should i have a set as a field or extend from another collection? what do u recommend?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with extending set. Just look in your books for a chapter on inheritance, and read about abstract methods. As to what I'd recommend, yeah, using a set as a variable sounds about right.

Comment: Ok I solved my problem, is this the correct "Scala way" https://github.com/Ang3lino/computational-theory/blob/master/Practice1/src/Alphabet.scala? I don't feel calling an instance variable it's right way in Scala. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You don't need `getSigma` - just make `sigma` public. Also, pretty much anything with `var` isn't really "a correct scala way". Just pretend that `var` and mutable containers do not exist for now, until you get enough of a feel for the language to be able to tell the 1% of cases where they are really needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class or trait you need to implement its abstract ("unimplemented") members (including its inherited abstract members). If you're extending `mutable.Set`, you have to implement the functions that a Scala mutable set is expected to have, namely (in your case):

```
// Members declared in scala.collection.GenSetLike
def iterator: Iterator[String]

// Members declared in scala.collection.SetLike
def contains(elem: String): Boolean

// Members declared in scala.collection.mutable.SetLike
def -=(elem: String): Alphabet
def +=(elem: String): Alphabet
```

`iterator` should construct an Iterator for the Set, so it can be iterated upon.

`contains` should check the set for the existence of `elem`, which in your case is a string.

`-=` should delete the given `elem` and return an `Alphabet`.

`+=` should add `elem` to the set and return an Alphabet.

You can find out more in the docs for [GenSetLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/collection/GenSetLike.html), [SetLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/collection/SetLike.html) and [mutable.SetLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/collection/mutable/SetLike.html).

Comment: Oye hermano y ¿como las implementaría? He intentado usando las palabras this y super, varias combinaciones y nada. He resuelto el problema agregando un conjunto como campo a la clase (es decir, sin extender) pero al hacer eso, por ejemplo,si quisiera recorrer los elementos llamando a la variable de instancia de la clase y no a la propia clase, cosa que siento que en Scala es más apropiado, por favor, ayuda.

Comment: I think that goes beyond the scope of the question, and the topic of inheritance usually takes up complete chapters in Object-Oriented Programming books. I suggest you read [Programming in Scala](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Comprehensive-Step-Step/dp/0981531644) so you get a better explanation on `extends`, `override`, `this` and `super` than any I could write in a few hundred characters. I mean this in the best way possible, as it's a prerequisite for more advanced stuff down the road.